# CSS can't undo transform: skewY?

Tags: html, css

So, I rotated a div using `transform: skewY(8deg);`, I wanted to rotate the div's content back to it's original state using `transform: skewY(-8deg);`, while it does kind of work, it doesn't seem to have an effect on `a#buy`. Is there a way around it, or an easy fix?

My HTML:

```
<div class="offers">
            <div id="offer1">
                <img id="ak" src="./img/AK.png">
                <p id="name">AK</p>
                <p id="price">57,53€</p>
                <p id="wear">0.0647</p>
                <a id="buy" href="linkhere">Buy</a>
            </div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
div.offers {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    margin-top: 632px;
    text-align: center;
    height : 400px;
}

div.offers div#offer1 {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #514538;
    width: 250px;
    height: 350px;
    border: 2px solid #FFA500;
    margin: auto;
    transform: skewY(8deg);
    margin-top: 50px;
}

div.offers div#offer1 p#name, p#price, p#wear, a#buy {
    transform: skewY(-8deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're talking only about the buy href? You can fix this by changing it's display property. Same for any other elements that have this in the future. The href is **inline** so it will ignore properties such as skew but also margin until you make it either for example **inline-block** or **block**.

So simply do:

```
a#buy {
   display: inline-block;
   /*or*/
   /*display: block;*/
}
```

Also while you're at it. Why not change #buy to a class (.buy) instead? It seems like a property you might re-use more often. Same for some of the other id's.

Comment: Thank you, adding `display: inline-block` to `a#buy` solved my issue